# Flutter Get Number Value from Currency format

Tags: dart, flutter

currently my textfield display in currency format example
IDR 120.000

and i want to get the value as 120000, how can i get that value easily?

Answer (score 1):

I would split at the space and parse the remaining part:

```
var numValue = double.tryParse(currValue.split(' ')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numbers by using this

```
final regDigit = RegExp(r'\d+');

final strValue = 'IDR 120.000';

print(strValue.replaceAll(regDigit, '')); // output => 120000
```

An Extension to format numbers into Indian currency format:

```
final regDigit = RegExp(r'\d+');

extension digitExtractor on String {
  
  String get extractString {
    //return this.replaceAll(regDigit, '');
    return regDigit.allMatches(this).map((match) => match.group(0)).join();
  }
  
  int get extractInt {
    // parse or default 0
    return int.tryParse(extractString) ?? 0;
  }
}
```

Now you can get value easily by using it like this:

```
final strValue = 'IDR 120.000';

print(strValue.extractString); // to get value in string

print(strValue.extractInt); // to get value in int
```